# Ubuntu DDE performance glitches

Tags: launcher, deepin-desktop-environment

I have installed the DE on top of Ubuntu Budgie 20.10 today following the instructions [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/how-to-install-deepin-desktop.html).

After rebooting and updating/ upgrading I still get some erroneous behaviour: the icons in the launcher are unresponsive and I have to add the icons to the menu bar in order to launch an application. When I click on the top left and right corner icons inside the launcher, it simply closes and does not resize.

The launcher itself won't open after this and I have to change the mode to regain control. Any idea why this happens and what I can do?